# PL/SQL stored function return with row type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lab( f_name IN VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN test%ROWTYPE
IS
    total NUMBER := 0;

    CURSOR c_app IS
        SELECT count(*),LISTAGG(s.sname,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.sname)
        FROM APPLICANT a INNER JOIN SPOSSESSED s ON a.A# = s.A# 
        WHERE a.fname = f_name;
    rec_app c_app%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_app;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_app into rec_app;
        EXIT WHEN c_app%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_app;
    RETURN rec_app;
END lab;
/
```

Fail to compile with errors that `expression wrong type`?
Isn't it possible to return with `rowtype` result?

for example i run this function

```
select lab(fname) from position where fname='PETER';
```

so the result will be display like

```
PETER : aaaa,bbbb,cccc
```

Comment: You're declaring the return as `test%rowtype`, then trying to return `rec_app` which is `c_app%rowtype` - so they don't match. You can't do that. It would help to show the actual error message(s) you get though.

Comment: so how i need to fix this ya? can teach?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you want the caller of this function to get back - a single row, or everything from the cursor? What is `test`?

Comment: return everything from the cursor.

Comment: it's not a table. i just simply want it to output in a rowtype only.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the return as `test%rowtype`, then trying to return `rec_app`, which is declared as `c_app%rowtype` - so the types don't match. You can't do that.

`c_app` is only in scope within this function so it would not have any meaning for any callers, and you can't use it as the return type. You can return something that is actually `test%rowtype`, assuming `test` is a table, but not an arbitrary different type. It isn't clear that there is any relationship at all between your cursor and its row type, and the `test` table.

You're also looping round to potentially fetch multiple rows, but only returning the last one (or trying to, anyway), which probably isn't what you mean to do.

The simplest way to get all the cursor rows back to the caller is with a ref cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lab( f_name IN VARCHAR2 )
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
    ref_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN ref_cur FOR
        SELECT count(*),LISTAGG(s.sname,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.sname)
        FROM APPLICANT a INNER JOIN SPOSSESSED s ON a.A# = s.A# 
        WHERE a.fname = f_name;
    RETURN ref_cur;
END lab;
/
```

If you create an external type you could use `PIPELINED` but that doesn't appear necessary here. neither is quite using a `%rowtype` though. You can only return a `%rowtype` if you have a table that has the columns you want to return.

Comment: so when i fetch the c_app , isnt fetch into the test ?

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch into the test"?